# Identification of an insect found near the Rhine, Germany

Tags: entomology

[image][image]

It was about 2-3cm long
It has two small wings and 6 legs

Comment: Is that the only photo you have? A side view would be very helpful.

Comment: possibly larval cicada, but I don't have access right now to figure out if true.

Comment: It would be helpful to know the size.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer and yes I have more pictures just not as good quality.

Comment: Also I wrote the size under the picture it was about 2-3 cm long

Comment: That side view is very helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 8):

It is the larva of a hemimetabolous insect for sure. Considering it was close to a water body I would say a nymph of some Odonata ?
The legs are a bit bulky though, I might be completely wrong.
These are not wings yet, they will be there at adult emergence.

Maybe check these out :
https://www.pentaxforums.com/gallery/photo-dragonfly-nymph-20082/

https://www.flyfishbc.com/threads/april-2011-fly-o-the-month-dragonfly-nymph-gomphus.5843/

Edit : my colleague Dirk Mikolajewski says it is a Gomphidae larvae. He will probably tell you which species soon.

Comment: Nice links! (Not a very pretty insect, though.) +1

Comment: Odonata larvae are the only insect I am scared of. I resent them a lot for eating amphibians.

Comment: I'm relieved to read that. I thought, "That thing would scare me to death!" It looks like it could take a chunk out of someone's hand, too.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help

Comment: I also have a short video of it Walking but can't upload here I think